# How to copy books from iPad iBooks to PC?

Tags: ipad, books, copy-paste

I have some books in iBooks on iPad 2 (iOS 5) that were manually transfered to iPad via iTunes (without syncing). How can I copy back a book to my PC, from iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Sync the ipad with books selected then you get a message asking you to transfer purchases, that should work shouldn't it?